# Fastest way of using has_key() inside filter()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I know this is a very efficient way in python 2, to intersect 2 dictionaries

```
filter(dict_1.has_key, dict_2.keys())
```

However `has_key()` was removed from Python3, so I can't really use the fast `filter()` and `has_key()` functions. What I'm doing right now is:

```
[key for key in dict_2 if key in dict_1]
```

But it seems a bit janky, on top of not being so much readable. Is this really the new fastest way with python3, or is there a faster, cleaner way by using `filter()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `has_key` in Python 2, you can use the `in` operator in Python 3.x. With `filter`, which gives a lazy iterator in 3.x, you can use `dict.__contains__`. There's also no need to call `dict.keys`:

```
res = filter(dict_1.__contains__, dict_2)    # lazy

print(list(res))
# [2, 3]
```

An equivalent, but less aesthetic, `lambda`-based solution:

```
res = filter(lambda x: x in dict_1, dict_2)  # lazy
```

A generator expression is a third alternative:

```
res = (x for x in dict_2 if ix in dict_1)    # lazy
```

For a non-lazy method, you can use `set.intersection` (or its syntactic sugar `&`):

```
res = set(dict_1) & set(dict_2)              # {2, 3}
```

Comment: `filter(dict_1.__contains__, dict_2)` is the faster way!

131 ns ± 1.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

Comment: @tpk, Be careful, `filter` is a lazy iterable in Python 3.x, it's not comparable to calculating the intersection in memory. You would need to compare with `list(filter(...))`.

Comment: Thanks, @jpp, I didn't know.

Updated run times.
`[key for key in d2 if key in d1]` : 290 ns ± 3.36 ns per loop 

`d1.keys() & d2.keys()` : 401 ns ± 1.41 ns per loop 

`list(filter(d1.__contains__, d2))` : 481 ns ± 2.21 ns per loop

`d1.keys() & d2` : 321 ns ± 1.05 ns per loop 
`set(d1).intersection(d2)` : 280 ns ± 4.66 ns per loop

For 7 runs, 1000000 loops each

Comment: Thanks for answering the exact question, using `filter`, on top of giving other useful solutions and useful insights!

Answer (score 5):

As you want the intersection of the keys, you could do:

```
d1 = {1 : 1, 2 : 2}
d2 = {1 : 3, 2 : 4, 3 : 5}

common = list(d1.keys() & d2.keys())
print(common)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Shorter: `d1.keys() & d2`, also `set(d1).intersection(d2)`

Comment: Good solution thanks! I felt I had to accept the other solution as it was using `filter` as stated in the title of the question and would be more useful for members stumbling here, but I really like the cleanliness of your solution!

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper No problem, thanks for the comment!